# NSLocalizedString unspecified language

Tags: swift, nslocalizedstring

I'm learning to translate my application, but I have a question.

What happens if the device language has not been put in the `Localizable.string`?
For example I want to use the word "Hello", in the file in English
I add `HELLO = "Hello"` in the file in Spanish I add `HELLO = "Hola"`
, in the file in French I add `HELLO = "Salut"`.
If the Iphone is in German, what will return `NSLocalizedString("HELLO",comment:"An initial greeting")`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app will use the **Base** localized file.

[image]

Comment: This does not work, if I define in Localizable.string (Base) , HELLO = "Hello", because my default language is English, and I execute it in an iPhone in German it does not return Hello, it returns Salut, the word in the language that was before, French .